# How to print a vector of boost::any, when i have the element types stored in another vector of strings?

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, stl, boost-any

- I'm using a vector of boost::any to store different data types, to construct a symbol table from a given program file.
- I'm also storing their datatypes in a separate vector as strings.
- while trying to print the boost::any using boost::any_cast<>(),
  if I pass the data type stored as string as cast type, I get a bad_any_cast error.
- How to overcome this hurdle and print the vector with the type info that I have as strings.

  ```
  vector<boost::any> vany;
  vector<string> vtype;
  string vartype;

  vany.push_back(10);
  vtype.push_back("int");
  vany.push_back(2.5);
  vtype.push_back("float");
  vany.push_back("hello");
  vtype.push_back("string");

  for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
  {
      vartype = vtype[i];
      cout<<boost::any_cast<vartype>(vany[i]); //this doesn't work, how do i make it work?
  }
  ```

Answer (score 4):

C++ is a statically typed language. Every expression must have a type which is know at *compile time*.

The value of a string (or any non-`constexpr` variable) is defined at *runtime*. As such, you cannot perform a cast to a type named by a string.

`any` is only useful if you know exactly what type was stored in that particular value. And you must know this at *compile time*, not runtime. It's for hiding the data type between the person giving out the value and the person receiving it. But it isn't allowed to break C++'s static typing rules.

There is no generalized solution for being able to store any type in an array and then performing arbitrary operations on them. You could develop a type like `any`, which would be able to use polymorphic access to the actual type to invoke `operator<<` on the value. But you cannot do that from outside of the `any`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224915/how-to-print-boostany-to-a-stream?rq=1

Comment: +1 for that duplicate link :)
I managed to overload << operator to solve my purpose. But i'm facing problem while trying to read from a file to a boost::any.

(example)
boost::any value;
file >> value; //throws an error

I guess i need some kinda overloading for the >> operator now. Do you know of something that might be of help?