# Converting std::any into an unknown type

Tags: c++, c++17

If I have a `std::any` of an `std::string` or an `int`, how could I cast this into the type that's contained?

`std::any` has `type` on it, however I can't use this type to cast.

Example:

```
#include <any>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main(void) {
    std::any test = "things";
    std::any test2 = 123;

    // These don't work
    std::string the_value = (std::string) test;
    int the_value2 = (int) test2;

    std::cout << the_value << std::endl;
    std::cout << the_value2 << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any/any_cast

Comment: Note that `test` does not hold a `std::string`. `"things"` is not a `std::string`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you do not have a list of types among which the any holds one, you cannot convert the any to its type and operate on it as its real type.

You can store a type in an any, and an operation in that type as a function pointer on that any.  But this must be done at the moment of storage or when you *do* have a list (possibly with 1 element) of the possible types stored in the any.

C++ does *not* store sufficient information within an any to permit arbitrary code to be compiled on that type when it stores the value in the any.  C++ does not permit full "reification" at runtime.

[Type erasing type erasure, `any` questions?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38835747/1774667) Q&A by a stackoverflow user of ill repute gives an example of how to remember some operation on the contents of the `any` while still forgetting the type stored.

If you do have such a list of possible types, consider using `variant`.  `any` exists in the narrow window where you do not know the types stored at container design time, but do at both insert and removal.

In that narrow window, you can do runtime tests based off the typeid stored and cast to the known type using `any_cast`.

Answer (score 10):

You use `any_cast` to do the trick.  For example

```
auto a = std::any(12); 
std::cout << std::any_cast<int>(a) << '\n';
```

You can find more details from [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any/any_cast)

If you want to *dynamically* cast the value inside a `std::any`, you can try

```
if (a.type() == typeid(int)) {
    cout << std::any_cast<int>(a) << endl;
} else if (a.type() == typeid(float)) {
    cout <<  std::any_cast<float>(a) << endl;
}
```

Comment: I understand that I can do it that way, but I'm looking to cast without knowing the type

Comment: you mean use the type id to do a dynamic cast?

Comment: @innectic The types (`std::string` and `int`) are known in your example too though.  Can you give an example involving "unknown types"?