# Possibility of store object type for std::any

Tags: c++, metaprogramming, c++17, std

In c++17 we have the [std::any](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any) which stores variable type of object in memory. Good part is I can create a vector of std::any to simulate a container for arbitrary type of object.

Whenever to query back the object from the container one will use  [std::any_cast](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any/any_cast) with the exact same type when calling [std::make_any](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any/make_any) to create the *any* object. Here is the snippet of how I achieve this

```
#include <any>
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <vector>
#include <set>

int main()
{
    /* create some objects */
    std::set<int> mySet = { 1, 2, 3 };
    std::vector<int> myVec = { 3, 4, 5 };
    std::unordered_map<int, std::vector<int>> myHash = { std::make_pair(1, myVec) };
    /* create any store */
    std::vector<std::any> anyStore;
    anyStore.push_back(std::make_any<decltype(mySet)>(mySet));
    anyStore.push_back(std::make_any<decltype(myVec)>(myVec));
    anyStore.push_back(std::make_any<decltype(myHash)>(myHash));
    /* get object back */
    auto newSet = std::any_cast<decltype(mySet)>(anyStore[0]);
    auto newVec = std::any_cast<decltype(myVec)>(anyStore[1]);
    auto newHash = std::any_cast<decltype(myHash)>(anyStore[2]);

    /* Question is can we store the decltype(mySet) in memory so that 
     * it can be read back while query from the vector to do any_cast?
     */

    return 0;
}
```

The question is as follows:
Is it possible to store the `decltype(mySet)` as run time variable so that we can use it in any_cast to auto resolve the type we want to get? I know probably you cannot store the type in memory since it is compile time variable, but is there workaround like using [std::type_index](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_index) or [std::type_info](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_info) to achieve goal?

Edit: 
Per @KerrekSB 's request. Here is an example usage of this dynamic sized container of std::any to create a class with dynamic properties.

```
#include <any>
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <vector>
#include <set>
#include <string>

class FooWithDynamic
{
public:
    FooWithDynamic() = default;

    template <class T>
    void RegisterProperty(const std::string &key, const T &obj)
    {
        m_store.emplace(key, std::make_any<T>(obj));
    }

    template <class T>
    T GetProperty(const std::string &key)
    {
        if (m_store.find(key) == m_store.end())
            throw;
        return std::any_cast<T>(m_store[key]);
    }
private:
    std::unordered_map<std::string, std::any> m_store;
};

int main()
{
    /* create some objects */
    FooWithDynamic foo;
    foo.RegisterProperty("mySet", std::set<int>{ 1, 2, 3 });
    foo.RegisterProperty("myVec", std::vector<int>{ 1, 2, 3 });
    foo.RegisterProperty("myHash", std::unordered_map<int, int>{ std::make_pair(1, 2) });
    /* query back object */
    auto mySet = foo.GetProperty<std::set<int>>("mySet");
    auto myVec = foo.GetProperty<std::vector<int>>("myVec");
    auto myHash = foo.GetProperty<std::unordered_map<int, int>>("myHash");
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks everyone to let me know this is not possible because it is in contrast of C++'s static typed philosophy.

Comment: Can you show some hypothetical *use* of this feature, assuming it exists?

Comment: @KerrekSB for example if I have a big metadata list which contains objects of different types, instead of creating a struct with a lot of members I can simply create a hashmap of query string to std::any object and if I can store the type of std::any in memory I can get the metadata back quite conveniently. Maybe not a good example, I am just exploring the possibility here.

Comment: @yc2986: And how would you access it? I mean, what would your code look like that tries to do anything with that data? If you don't know at the time you're writing your code what type it is, what exactly would you be able to do with it?

Comment: @yc2986: Please provide a fully typed out piece of example code showing the use case.

Comment: @KerrekSB I will come up with one. Please wait for a moment. Thanks!

Comment: @KerrekSB here is my original thought of "if I can have this dynamic type resolve what I want to do".

Comment: Are either the types or the operations on the instances finite or enumerable in one place?  If so, maybe.

Comment: @yc2986: Thanks -- but your example looks like it's already well-formed C++. What feature are you missing? What I'd like to see is an example of how you would use your *hypothetical* new feature, so that we can offer solutions.

Comment: @KerrekSB, to link that example to my question, for function ```GetProperty``` is it possible to use some sort of pre stored runtime variable to auto resolve the type casting. With all the answer below it seems I cannot achieve it with a dynamic container like unordered_map since c++ is strictly static typed.

Comment: @yc2986: My question remains: how would you *use* the result? Just making a variable as in your current example isn't a real use case. Can you flesh this out further to then *do* something with those variables in a way that wouldn't require you to know their type?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is it possible to store the decltype(mySet) as run time variable

No. C++ is a statically typed language. Types cannot be determined at runtime. The type of every expression, like the return value of a function that would return the value stored in the `any`, must be known at *compile time*.

That's precisely why you have to supply the type explicitly when you `any_cast`.

Comment: It seems std::any will throw static assertion if you supply wrong any_cast type. Can this be used to achieve the auto resolve of any_cast?

Comment: @yc2986: No. What part of "statically typed language" and "the type of every expression ... must be known at compile time" do you not understand? If `any_cast` could take a runtime value, what would its return type be?

Comment: Yea I understand cpp is a static type language and runtime variable cannot be used to determine a compile time type. So does this make a final conclusion of: there is no way in current C++ to store any form of type information that can be used at runtime to do type casting.

Comment: @yc2986: There's *never* going to be a way for C++ to perform casting based on runtime information. Being able to do so would violate the very nature of C++.

Comment: Thanks for the elaboration, I will remember this as the rule of thumb from now on :)

Comment: @NicolBolas A problem with this answer is that it completely neglects to mention type erasure.  You can both generate and store *operations on specific types*, and even runtime maps from types to operations.  This isn't *exactly* what the OP wants, but it often solves the problem the OP is talking about.

Comment: @Yakk: But that's not what he asked for. He didn't ask for a wrapper around a specific set of generic operations. He said he wants a "run time variable" that can be used to cast `any` to the type that it stores.

Answer (score 2):

No. C++ is not a dynamically typed language. Even when a variable is declared `auto`, its type is fixed at compile time---it just makes it so that you don't have to write out the type of the right-hand side yourself. It is impossible to declare a variable whose type depends on runtime information---unless all the possible types have a common base class.

Most of the time, `std::any` is not useful for precisely this reason: when you have a collection of objects and you erase their types in this way, those objects usually become useless. If you don't know what they are, then you can't do anything with them.

Are you sure you don't want to use `std::variant` instead? Or `std::tuple`? Or templates?

Comment: std::tuple seems to be fixed size. What I want probably is a dynamic container which can store arbitrary type of object.

Comment: @yc2986 then once you have that container you no longer have any information left about what you can actually do with the objects it contains

Answer (score 0):

If your operations and/or types are enumerable in certain ways (finite, for example), then you can solve this problem.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38835747/1774667) is an example of some systems that pack an `any` with operations on it.  Then whenever you store a value in the `any`, the operations are automatically written and stored.

At a later time you can invoke the operations on the object stored in the `any` without ever knowing what the type is.

This does require knowing *what operations you need to be able to perform on the contents of the `any`* before you store them.  Alternatively, if you find partial functions acceptable, you can store have it only work on a subset of possible types stored.

You can store a map from `typeindex` to some operation, check if an `any` has a type matching any of the keys, if so, invoke the operation, if not, flag an error.

C++ does not have runtime reification, barring shipping a C++ compiler with your product, compiling a custom DLL, then dynamically loading it.  (And no, don't do this)  But you can often solve problems that naively would be solved via reification through various type erasure techniques.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, the question you posted is certainly a good read. As for my part I am curious of whether I can achieve a dynamic data store which not only can be resized at will but also can store the type as runtime variable to auto resolve the anycast issue when you want to query it. If I limit the problem to a fixed size store I can use tuple to solve the issue as Brian stated above. Thanks for the answer again!