# C++: check if the value stored in std::any is integral

Tags: c++, c++20, stdany

There's a value stored in `std::any` and I want to know if it's an integral value (`char`, `short`, `int`, `long`, both signed and unsigned) or a floating point value (`float`, `double`), or something else.

If I only had to check for `int` values, I would do this:

```
std::any a;
if (a.type() == typeid(int)) {
  // do some logic for int
}
```

But to do a giant `if (a.type() == typeid(int) || a.type() == typeid(signed char)...)` for all the integral types in C++ seems... bad.

I could use `is_arithmetic<T>` from `type_traits` if I had the type `T` accessible somehow but I don't, I only have `std::any#type()` which returns `std::type_info`.

Is there a way to accomplish this without many, many disjunctions in the `if` condition?

(I'm using C++20 if it's important)

Comment: [`std::any_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any/any_cast) and catch the thrown exception if it's the wrong type? But note that `int` can be converted to just about any other numeric type, so this might not work. With that said, generally speaking, using `typeid` to select program paths is typically a sign of bad design.

Comment: That is how std any works and that’s how limited it is. If you want something more fancy use your how type erasure (e.g. built on top of std any) or use another library, like Boost.TypeErasure https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_76_0/doc/html/boost_typeerasure.html. The key is that you are looking for a Concept based type erasure rather than type based.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`std::any` is a type erasure class.

It only remembers the exact type, and the ability to cast back to that exact type (plus how to copy/move/destroy it).

If you want to remember *other* facts about a type stored, you have to do the work yourself.

There is no way to get at the `T` within `std::any` without checking for that exact `T`.

In general, using `std::any` to shove "anything" into it with no control results in a mess.  `std::any` allows you to do this with an "open" set of types, so you can safely pass data from one spot of code to another while the intermediate code doesn't need to know what it is.

It does not give you the ability to generate type-aware code using an unknown type.

---

To solve your problem, there are a number of solutions.

1. If your set of types you support is closed (fixed somehow), use `std::variant`.
2. If the set of types is mostly closed, use `std::variant< bunch, of, types, std::any >`.  Then you can deal with the "mostly closed" types as a `variant`.  Using code that blocks conversion to `std::any` if the type input can be converted-to any other type might be wise.
3. If you are comfortable writing your own type erasure, you can write your own or augment `std::any` with extra information.
4. You can write a utility function that does the massive if statement, possibly using templates, in time linear in the number of types.

For 1/2,

```
auto is_integral_f = [](auto&& x){ return std::is_integral<std::decay_t<decltype(x)>>{}; };

std::variant<int,char,unsigned int, long, double, std::any> bob;
bob = 3;
assert( std::visit( is_integral_f, bob ) );
```

For 3, [here is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38835747/type-erasing-type-erasure-any-questions/38865269) of an engine that makes type erasure this way a bit simpler; writing it yourself is possible.  Then we simply:

```
auto is_integral = any_method<bool()>{ is_integral_f };

super_any<decltype(is_integral)> my_any;

my_any bob = 3;
my_any alice = 3.14;
assert( (bob->*is_integral)() );
assert( !(alice->*is_integral)() );
```

For 4,

```
template<class...Ts>
bool is_any_of_types( std::any const& a ) {
  return (( a.type() == typeid(Ts) ) || ... );
}
```

which is linear in `sizeof...(Ts)`.

You could get fancy with hashes if `Ts...` is large, but I doubt it will get large enough.  You still need to enumerate the types yourself; `is_integral<T>` cannot be inverted by the C++ language.

Comment: a query into a set of `std::type_index`es of allowed int types might be an option

Comment: @sopel yes, even a hash table.