# Making boost::spirit::hold_any accept vectors

Tags: c++, boost-spirit

According to its author @hkaiser, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224915/how-to-print-boostany-to-a-stream) `boost::spirit::hold_any` is a more performant alternative to `boost::any` and can, for the most part, be used as a drop-in replacement for the latter. I'm interested in it since it purports to allow for easy output streaming, a feature that `boost::any` lacks.

While I'm able to input simple types like `int` into `hold_any`, I can't seem to get it to hold a container such as `std::vector<int>` for example. Here'e the code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/spirit/home/support/detail/hold_any.hpp> // v1.79
#include <vector>
using any = boost::spirit::hold_any;

int main() {
    int a1 = 1;
    any v1(a1); // OK
    std::cout << v1 << std::endl; // OK
    std::vector<int> w2 = {5,6};
    any v2(w2); // compilation error - invalid operands to binary expression ('std::basic_istream<char>' and 'std::vector<int>')
    std::cout << v2 << std::endl;
}
```

which fails to compile with

```
hold_any.hpp:155:23: error: invalid operands to binary expression ('std::basic_istream<char>' and 'std::vector<int>')
                    i >> *static_cast<T*>(*obj);
```

Presumably, the `std::vector<int>` needs to be made istream streamable though I'm not sure how to proceed. How does one make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, that advice is 12 years old. Since then `std::any` was even standardized. I would not assume that `hold_any` is still the better choice (on the contrary).

Also, note that the [answer you implied](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3225254/85371) contains the exact explanation:

> This class has two differences if compared to boost::any:
>
> - it utilizes the small object optimization idiom and a couple of other optimization tricks, making `spirit::hold_any` smaller and faster than `boost::any`
> - it ***has the streaming operators (`operator<<()` and `operator>>()`)*** defined, allowing to input and output a spirit::hold_any seemlessly.

(***emphasis*** mine)

Incidentally, the whole question was about streaming `any` in the first place, so the answer was on-point there.

The code further drives home the assumption:

```
// these functions have been added in the assumption that the embedded
// type has a corresponding operator defined, which is completely safe
// because spirit::hold_any is used only in contexts where these operators
// do exist
    template <typename Char_>
    friend inline std::basic_istream<Char_>&
    operator>> (std::basic_istream<Char_>& i, basic_hold_any<Char_>& obj)
    {
        return obj.table->stream_in(i, &obj.object);
    }

    template <typename Char_>
    friend inline std::basic_ostream<Char_>&
    operator<< (std::basic_ostream<Char_>& o, basic_hold_any<Char_> const& obj)
    {
        return obj.table->stream_out(o, &obj.object);
    }
```

So, indeed that explains the requirement. It's a bit unfortunate that the implementation is not SFINAE-ed so that you'd only run into the limitation if you used the `stream_in`/`stream_out` operations, but here we are.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make the above code work by making a generic vector `std::vector<T>` both output and *input* streamable.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/spirit/home/support/detail/hold_any.hpp>
#include <vector>
using any = boost::spirit::hold_any;

namespace std {
    // input stream
    template<typename T>
    std::istream& operator >> ( std::istream& ins, std::vector<T>& p ) {
        size_t sz;
        ins >> sz;
        for ( size_t i = 0; i < sz; ++i ) {
            T tmp;
            ins >> tmp;
            p.push_back( tmp );
        }
        return ins;
    }
    // output stream
    template<typename T>
    std::ostream& operator << ( std::ostream& outs, const std::vector<T>& p ) {
        outs << "[";
        for ( size_t i = 0; i < p.size(); ++i ) {
            outs << p[i];
            if ( i != p.size() - 1 )
                outs << " ";
            else
                outs << "]";
        }
        return outs;
    }
}
```

I'd appreciate any comments on how to make the above more performant. `boost::iostreams` perhaps?

Comment: Performance of container pretty printing is its own separate question. I'd suggest searching for existing answers or asking the new question